# ColdFusion structkey starting with number

Tags: variables, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Why does this fail:

```
<CFIF isdefined("URL.3dfile")>...</CFIF>
```

with following message:

> Parameter 1 of function IsDefined, which is now URL.3dfile, must be a syntactically valid variable name.

and this won't:

```
<CFIF structkeyexists(URL,"3dfile")>...</CFIF>
```

Is the way it get's parsed not much the same? And .. are variables starting with numbers invalid or aren't they?

Comment: Actually the way the two get parsed is not much the same. You should try to eschew isDefined() in favor of structKeyExists(); the latter is more efficient (at least that is the received wisdom ;-)).

Comment: isDefined() covers any kind of variable that might have a dot. That can include structs, queries, objects, etc. structkeyexists() only works if the first parameter is a struct. Having said that, i surprised the first one works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seybsen - variables names should not begin with a number. This is likely a legacy of older non-java version of CF Where a variable was not part of an object.

However, in the java world everything IS an object. This leads to a syntactical nuance. If you are using variable names in dotted notation your var name will likely throw an error. But use it in other ways and it will succeed.

So this sort of syntax works 
    `url['33foo']`

But setting a variable name directly - `33foo = true` - will not work.

Here's a post with a full explanation.

http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2005/9/8/isdefined%20vs%20structkeyexists

Comment: You might also like to review the documentation on [variable naming rules](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd3.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fde)